# Does block object cause retain cycle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have this code:

```
@implementation example
{
    NSString *myObject;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    __block NSString* blockObject = myObject;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0),^(void){
        blockObject = @"Hello world";    
    });
}
```

Now because I am using __block, a strong reference is made to self, because I am accessing an instance variable by reference and not by value.

So the above code is the same as:

```
@implementation example
{
    NSString *myObject;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,0),^(void)  {
        myObject = @"Hello world";    
    });
}
```

So dealloc method will not called until the block exit. My compiler use arc!

Comment: Have you tried it and got some conclusion.

Comment: i am trying now , and want to share my question !

Comment: David I've tried it :[ checkout my answer

Comment: ok I just want to be sure that's correct, I will do some tests ! thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
__block NSString* blockObject = myObject;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0),^(void){
        blockObject = @"Hello world";    
    });
```

The above code will not strongly hold the `self` and thus your `dealloc` **will be called** before the `block` exits. Why it will not strongly hold the `self` is because you are creating a new variable `blockObject` and block will strongly hold this variable not the ivar thus not retaining the `self`

---

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,0),^(void)  {
        myObject = @"Hello world";    
    });
```

The above code will strongly hold the `self` and `dealloc` **will not be called** until `block` exits.

Answer (score 1):

The two example in your question are in fact very different.

The first results in NO CHANGE to your instance variable `myObject` whereas the second changes it to "Hello world".

Comment: could you please provide more explanation

Answer (score 0):

Usually if I have to access instance variables, I write something like this... fyi. pseudocode

```
__weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,0),^(void)  {
    __strong typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;
    strongSelf->myObject = @"Hello world";    
});
```

Comment: i think you should do that example * __weak blockSelf = self; ! right ?

Comment: Don't write that. If `weakSelf` is `nil` when the block executes, you'll dereference a NULL pointer and raise an exception. `->` is not a method dispatch.